# When postfix increment actually increase the variable in C?

Tags: c

```
int  i = 8;
int  b = (i++) + (i++) + (i++);
```

In the above code,When actually `i` increase?
I'm not familiar with C,it turns out `i` will increase after each postfix increment execute in Java.
Does anyone knows the detail?

Comment: Not again, please.

Comment: Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point

Comment: @devnull, I think this one is not UB. I'm deleting my answer.

Comment: Is `b = i++` also undefined behavior? The suggested duplicate talks only about `i = i++`.

Comment: @Juhana (i++) + (i++) is undefined.

Comment: Note that C and Java are different languages with different rules; what's true for one isn't necessarily true for the other.